# When RTMP is phased out, what will social media companies use for ingesting streams?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming, rtmp, hls

From what I've read RTMP is the best low latency solution for sending streams and other current technologies are designed for P2P streaming (WebRTC) and consuming streams (HLS & Dash) (Dash I need to look into more).. Anyways, looks like RTMP is currently the go to for SM companies ingesting streams. What will they do now that Adobe is ending support in 2020?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody knows yet. SRT, WebRTC, and RIST so far seem to be the best bets. But just like any technology war there will not be a winner declared until one wins.

Also, RTMP does not require adobe support to continue. Nobody is use Adobe software for RTMP anymore anyway. Adobe lost control over RTMP half a decade ago.